# C++ for loop input

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I have made a project using structure and pointers to display a person identity. Most of it works fine but when it come to for loop, it just messes up the entire program. The main idea was to work in this way

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++{
    cout << "Whatever" << endl;
    getline(cin, var_whatever[i]);
}
```

So it would run the loop 3 times and ask the user to input it 3 times but when this runs, it skips over the first input and goes to the second one. Here's my code and would be grateful if someone gives me a solution to this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

//declare structure to store info about Billy
struct Son{
    string name;
    int age;
    string crush;
    string hobbies[3];
}Person;

int main(){
    int i;
    Son* info = new Son;
    info = &Person;
    //user interface
    //Person's name
    cout << "Person's name: ";
    getline(cin, info ->name); //inputs person's name
    //Person's age
    cout << "Person's age: ";
    cin >> info ->age; //inputs person's age
    //for loop to get hobbies
    for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++){ //main problem which is giving me headache
        cout << "Write your hobby[" << i <<"]: ";
        getline(cin,info ->hobbies[i]); //inputs the person hobby three times
    }
    //Person's crush
    cout << "Write your crush name: ";
    getline(cin, info ->crush); //inputs the person's crush *opitional*

    //output statement
    cout << "Name: " << info ->name << endl; //display name
    cout << "Age: " << info ->age << endl; //display age
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){ //display hobbies
    cout << "Hobbies[" << j << "]: " << info ->hobbies[j] << endl;
    }
    cout << "Crush: " << info ->crush << endl; //display crush
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is

```
Person's name: Billy
Person's age: 25
Write your hobby[0]: Write your hobby[1]:soccer
write your hobby[2]:basketball
write your hobby[3]:Kungfu
Write your crush name: Jake
Name:Billy
Age:25
Hobbies[0]:
Hobbies[1]:soccer
Hobbies[2]:basketball
Crush: Jake
```

This code output is hell and anyway
Thank You for your time

Comment: Also a beginner in c++ so just learning

Comment: What a dramatic title man.

Comment: The code extract and the main code don't match.

Comment: Note: `for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++)` will cause a *segmentation fault*, remember that arrays are *zero-based*.

Comment: Please don't say "everything works fine". Don't say it ever, but *especially* not if you have a situation that isn't working fine at all.

Comment: @Jim I updated the title to be less over-dramatic, and more descriptive of the *actual* problem you're having.

Comment: That is a lot of code to describe a problem

Answer (score 2):

```
//for loop to get hobbies
for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
```

should be

```
//for loop to get hobbies
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
```

You are running the loop for `i` as 0, 1, 2, and 3. It should be 0, 1, and 2.

Also, it will generally be easier for you to handle input consistently if you read lines (`getline`), or read tokens (`>>`), but not both.

```
cout << "Person's age: ";
string age;
cin >> age;
info->age = atoi(age.c_str()); // add #include <cstring> at the top.
```

Comment: Well I did liked your explanation @Paul Draper but no sure if you mentioned about for loop skipping over the first input

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
 cin >> info ->age
```

The problem is that it reads (presumably an int) the age. But it does not read the end of line marker. So you have an extra EOLM left on the stream. When you then use this in combination with a command that reads a line `getline()` it usually messes things up unless you take precautions.

The problem is caused by mixing `operator>>` and `std::getline()`. In this situation you read the age (but leave the EOLM on the stream. The first call to `std::getline()` will simply read the EOLM from the stream (and nothing else).

The best way to solve this is to always read interactive user input a line at a time. Then parse out the value you want from the line.

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);

std::stringstream linestream(line);
linestream >>  info->age;
```

I would give this advice for almost any language, e.g. Java's `java.util.Scanner.next()` and `java.util.Scanner.nextLine()`.

Comment: Thanks this really helped and thanks to you  and @Paul Draper for helping out.